# Simple Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, word-frequency, isalpha

The question asks to write a function creating a dictionary with the count of each word in the string and only remove the punctuation if it is the last character in the word. I've been trying to solve the punctuation part of the problem. For the assignment I need to identify the punctuation using `isalpha`, but

1. I'm not sure if using the `word[-1]` is helping to identify if the last character is punctuation and
2. I don't know how to write the else statement to get the full dictionary to produce.

```
def word_distribution(s):

    s = s.lower()
    s = s.split()
    wordfreq = {}
    for word in s:
        if word[-1].isalpha():
            if word in wordfreq:
                wordfreq[word] += 1 
            else:
                wordfreq[word] = 1

    return wordfreq
```

Example of what my code is producing...

```
word_distribution("Why's it always the nice guys?")
```

```
Out : {'always': 1, 'it': 1, 'nice': 1, 'the': 1}
```

Example of what it should be producing.....

```
Out : {'always': 1, 'it': 1, 'nice': 1, 'the': 1, 'why's': 1, 'guys': 1}
```

Comment: Format your question, add input and desired output example(s).

Comment: The problem here is that it is treating guys? as a single word and filtering out the response.

Comment: In this situation, punctuation can be left in the dictionary if it is not the last character of the word. @AnuragReddy

Comment: @Dinac23 My apologies, I'm brand new to stack overflow.  I think I have that in there? what else would you like?

Comment: Also, I have a question @Anfieldisonfire, how are you comparing with respect to an empty dictionary?

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite catch the example at the end of the post. Make sure to include the _def_ part of the code with the rest of the code.

Comment: This is also missing 'why' in the dict

Answer (score 1):

Generally for counting stuff, you should use the `collections.Counter` class, and for checking if an element is a `,` or `?` you should use `string.punctuation` that contains them, for example:

```py
import string
from collections import Counter
txt = "Why's it always the nice guys?"

counted = Counter(
    word if not word[-1] in string.punctuation else word[:-1] for word in txt.split()
)
print(counted)

>>> Counter({"Why's": 1, 'it': 1, 'always': 1, 'the': 1, 'nice': 1, 'guys': 1})
```

Now if you really need a dictionary for output just do:

```py
print(dict(counted))

>>> {"Why's": 1, 'it': 1, 'always': 1, 'the': 1, 'nice': 1, 'guys': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome on SO.

If I understand your problem, I think you simply wrote the construct `if then else` in the wrong way.

```
import string

def word_distribution(s):
    s = s.lower()
    s = s.split()
    wordfreq = {}
    for word in s:
        if word[-1] in string.punctuation:
            if word[-1] in wordfreq:
                wordfreq[word[:-1]] += 1 
            else:
                wordfreq[word[:-1]] = 1
        else:
            if word in wordfreq:
                wordfreq[word] += 1 
            else:
                wordfreq[word] = 1

    return wordfreq

x = word_distribution("Why's it always the nice guys?")
print(x)
```

I used `string.punctuation` to check if the last character is a punctuation symbol.

The output is: `{"why's": 1, 'it': 1, 'always': 1, 'the': 1, 'nice': 1, 'guys': 1}`

Edit:
Another solution using `isalpha`:

```
def word_distribution(s):
    s = s.lower()
    s = s.split()
    wordfreq = {}
    for word in s:
        if word[-1].isalpha():
            if word[-1] in wordfreq:
                wordfreq[word] += 1 
            else:
                wordfreq[word] = 1
        else:
            if word in wordfreq:
                wordfreq[word[:-1]] += 1 
            else:
                wordfreq[word[:-1]] = 1

    return wordfreq

x = word_distribution("Why's it always the nice guys?")
print(x)
```

The output is: `{"why's": 1, 'it': 1, 'always': 1, 'the': 1, 'nice': 1, 'guys': 1}`